# Using a variable from another function python

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

Hey there, this is a very fundamental concept and I've looked it up and global variables are not working for me. I need to use the variable `score` which is in the function `main` in another function called `judgment`, so based on the score of the trivia, I can tell the user how they did (which is why I called the `judgment` function at the very bottom of `main`). It gives error that name `score` is not defined in `judgment` function.

Code:

```
# Trivia Challenge
# Trivia game that reads a plain text file

import sys

def open_file(file_name, mode):
    """Open a file."""
    try:
        the_file = open(file_name, mode)
    except IOError as e:
        print("Unable to open the file", file_name, "Ending program.\n", e)
        input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    """Return next line from the trivia file, formatted."""
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line

def next_block(the_file):
    """Return the next block of data from the trivia file."""
    category = next_line(the_file)

    question = next_line(the_file)

    answers = []
    for i in range(4):
        answers.append(next_line(the_file))

    correct = next_line(the_file)
    if correct:
        correct = correct[0]

    explanation = next_line(the_file)

    point = next_line(the_file)


    return category, question, answers, correct, explanation, point

def welcome(title):
    """Welcome the player and get his/her name."""
    print("\t\tWelcome to Trivia Challenge!\n")
    print("\t\t", title, "\n")

def judgement(score):

    if  score > 0 and score <= 5:
            print("You can do better.")
    elif score >= 6 and score <= 10: 
            print("You did okay.")
    elif score >= 11 and score <= 14:
            print("You did average.")
    elif score >= 15 and score <= 19:
            print("You did above average.")
    elif score >= 20 and score <= 24:
            print("You did excellent.")
    else:
        print("Does not exist.")

def main():
    trivia_file = open_file("trivia_points.txt", "r")
    title = next_line(trivia_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0

    # get first block
    category, question, answers, correct, explanation, point = next_block(trivia_file)
    while category:
        # ask a question
        print(category)
        print(question)
        for i in range(4):
            print("\t", i + 1, "-", answers[i])

        # get answer
        answer = input("What's your answer?: ")

        # check answer
        if answer == correct:
            print("\nRight!", end=" ")
            score += int(point)
        else:
            print("\nWrong.", end=" ")
        print(explanation)
        print("Score:", score, "\n\n")

        # get next block
        category, question, answers, correct, explanation, point = next_block(trivia_file)

    trivia_file.close()

    print("That was the last question!")
    print("You're final score is", score)

judgement(score)

main()  
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Contents of trivia_points.txt file:

```
An Episode You Can't Refuse
Tooth hurts?
Let's say your tooth hurts real bad. Where would you go?
Dentist
Butler
Optical
Pawn Shop
1
Because a dentist deals with teeth
2
Food for pets
Let's say you need to get your sea monster some food. Where is the best place to go?
Kroger
Pet's mart
Walmart
Target
2 
Because you can find food for most pets at pets mart.
2
Get in Shape
If you want to play tennis, where would you go?
Tennis Court
Basketball Court
Beach
Football field
1
Because you can play tennis on a tennis court. 
3
Loving Animals
What would you do if you came home to find your dog cooking dinner?
Beat the crap out of it
Let it destroy everything in the kitchen
Sell it 
Enjoy the dinner with him
4
Because dogs are human friends and we need to care for them. 
1
Feel like hunting
If you want to go fishing, what would you take with you?
Basketball
Tennis Ball
Soccer ball
Fishing Rod
4
A fishing rod might be able to help you catch some fish
2
Feeling Smart?
What is the best way to prepare for a jeopardy?
Eat a lot
Sleep a lot
Study a lot
Drink a lot 
3 
Because studying will help you win the game, obviously
2
Road trip
If you drove with 43 people from chicago to mississippi and picked two from texas, what is name of driver?
Jack
Bill
John
You
4
You, because you were the one who drove those people 
5
Sickness relieve
If doctor gave you 3 pills to take every .5 hours, how long until all of them are taken?
.5 hours
1 hour
2 hours
1.5 hours
2
1 hour, because you could take one right away to start with
4
Need for Speed
If I have to travel 4 miles on I-35 in traffic, what would I take?
The bus
The car
The speed bike
By foot
3
The speed bike because it could cut through traffic, even thoguh you could get a ticket
2
Time for Party
What would not be a smart move in a crowded bar or party?
Pay for your own drink 
Don't get in a fight
Make sure you bring your friend along
Take drinks from everyone 
4
Taking drinks from everyone wouldn't be smart, because that could be dangerous
1
```

Comment: Don't use external services like pastebin for referencing code. This is information is volatile and will go away soon. Not suitable for SO.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `judgement(score)` out of the scope of your `main()` function. The `score` variable is local in that function. Just indent that line to match the function indentation.

In Python, indentation has syntactical meaning, so you are not "calling judgment function at the very bottom of main" but before the main function call.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're calling `judgement(score)` before `main()` (both at the bottom of the script). Why don't you move the `judgement(score)` into `main`? Then `main`'s local copy of `score` will be copied into the local environment of `judgement`, and no globals are necessary.

Comment: thanks for the inputs. it did work. by moving judgment(score) into main, do you mean copy the contents or recreate that whole function down in the main function (so function in another function). didn't know you could do that

Comment: I meant just move the call (by indenting it, as @Fenikso said), keeping the function definition where it is. Glad it worked!